# Residual / explained variance TraMineR

Tags: r, anova, variance, traminer

Can someone explain to me, how the explained / residual variance from the `dissassoc` command is computed? I tried to add up the variance within using the discrepancies of the different levels, but it didn't work. Let's take a small random sample (n=10).

```
data(mvad)
library(dplyr) 
set.seed(10)

mv = mvad %>% group_by(male) %>% sample_n(5)
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mv[,17:20])

# compute the dissimilarity matrix
mvad.ham <- seqdist(mvad.seq, method="HAM") 

# compute the discrepancy analysis 
d = dissassoc(mvad.ham, group = mv$male, R=10) 
d 
# Pseudo ANOVA table:
#         SS df      MSE
# Exp    1.7  1 1.700000
# Res    9.6  8 1.200000
# Total 11.3  9 1.255556
```

I understand how to compute the `Total` by hand:

```
sum(mvad.ham) / (2* 10) # = Total 11.3
```

Questions:

1. How do you compute the `Exp` and `Res` values by hand?
2. Could you please demonstrate us how do you compute the Total Sum of Square?

I understand from (Studer et al., 2010) that the equation is:

$$ SS = \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i(y_i - \bar{y})^2 $$

What does the $\bar{y}$ represents exactly? Could you demonstrate on this example how one can compute the $SS$ from `mvad.ham` *manually*?

Comment: @giacomoV, I voted to reject this edit.  It is really the OP's job to provide an example of the problem they are having. We can't really know if this was it or something else. This thread should really just be closed.

Comment: @gung. I understand your point, but I am having exactly the same question and I dont want to ask it twice to professor Gilbert. Please do consider leave it open. I am 99% confident that it is the same question but the person didn't take the time to provide an example. I think this question is very important for the sequence community. Please again leave it open.

Comment: I politely disagree, @giacomoV. You should ask a new question, not hijack this one. If you ask a good question, it can get good answers (most likely better than what might happen here). Then we could close this as a duplicate of your new question.

Comment: @gung I posted my own question on the topic http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237792/sum-of-squares-of-a-distance-matrix-sequence-analysis-r-example

Answer (score 2):

We would need an example to see what you are making wrong. Nevertheless, from what you say I understand that you attempt to get the total within variance by adding up the variances of each group. It is the sums of squares $(SS = n \cdot var)$ that should be added up, not the variances.

The within SS of each group is computed the same way as the total SS. The sum of those within SS gives the residual SS.

The explained SS is then obtained as the difference between the total SS and the residual SS.

$SS_{exp} = SS_{tot} - SS_{res}$

I illustrate by building on your example:

```
(ss.tot <- sum(mvad.ham)/(nrow(mvad.seq)*2))
## [1] 11.3

ss.male <- sum(mvad.ham[mv$male=="yes",mv$male=="yes"])/(sum(mv$male=="yes")*2)
ss.female <- sum(mvad.ham[mv$male!="yes",mv$male!="yes"])/(sum(mv$male!="yes")*2)

(ss.res <- ss.female + ss.male)
## [1] 9.6

(ss.exp <- ss.tot - ss.res)
## [1] 1.7
```

Comment: I have the output:
  Pseudo ANOVA table:
          SS     df         MSE
Exp    9372.421    9 1041.380151
Res   29832.871 9990    2.986273
Total 39205.293 9999    3.920921

I know, how i can reproduce the Total variance on my own by computing 
sum(example.dist)/(2*n):

> (sum(org.om))/(2*10000)
[1] 39205.29

But how can I reproduce the explained variance? 
Is there a way in R to do this like the total variance?

Comment: I have completed the answer. Edit your question with your your example figures so that I can refer to them in the answer.

Comment: @giacomo I just discovered that I didn't follow up on the provided example. This is now done. Sorry for the long delay.