# Sums-of-Squares (total, between, within): how to compute them from a Distance Matrix?

Tags: anova, distance, sums-of-squares, sequence-analysis

I am having trouble understanding the concept of Sum of Squares in the context of distance matrices (Studer et al. 2010).

The Sum of Squares I am familiar with is the classical $SS$ from ANOVA, performed on contingency table, such as

```
 sex    FE employment joblessness school
  1    16          4           0      0
  2     8          3           1      8
```

From which I can quickly compute the ANOVA Sum of Squares with

```
dtm = melt(dt, id.vars = c('sex'))
dtmcount = count(dtm, sex, value)

dtmcount %>% group_by() %>% 
  mutate(grandmean = mean(n)) %>%
  group_by(sex) %>% 
  mutate(SumSqtTotal = (n - grandmean)^2) %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% mutate(groupmean = mean(n)) %>% 
  mutate(SSW = (n - groupmean)^2) %>%
  group_by(sex) %>% mutate(SSB = ( grandmean - groupmean)^2) %>%
  group_by() %>%
  summarise(SST = sum(SumSqtTotal), SSW = sum(SSW), SSB = sum(SSB))

  # results # 

  SST =  SSW    SSB
  53     20     33
```

The Sum of Squares makes sense to me because I understand that we are comparing **means** and decomposing means.

However, when it comes to distance matrices, I don't understand what the "mean" becomes.

Consider the same data, but this time we are comparing sequences.

```
   sex     Sep.93     Oct.93     Nov.93     Dec.93
1    1     school     school     school     school
2    1   training   training   training   training
3    1     school     school     school     school
4    1   training   training   training   training
5    1     school     school     school     school
6    2         FE         FE         FE         FE
7    2         FE         FE         FE         FE
8    2   training   training   training   training
9    2     school     school     school     school
10   2 employment employment employment employment
```

In a classical sequence analysis, we would use a distance algorithm to compute pairwise dissimilarities and end up with a distance matrix, like this one (from Hamming distance)

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    4    0    4    0    4    4    4    0     4
 [2,]    4    0    4    0    4    4    4    0    4     4
 [3,]    0    4    0    4    0    4    4    4    0     4
 [4,]    4    0    4    0    4    4    4    0    4     4
 [5,]    0    4    0    4    0    4    4    4    0     4
 [6,]    4    4    4    4    4    0    0    4    4     4
 [7,]    4    4    4    4    4    0    0    4    4     4
 [8,]    4    0    4    0    4    4    4    0    4     4
 [9,]    0    4    0    4    0    4    4    4    0     4
 [10,]   4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4     0
```

The analysis of variance for sequence analysis was developed by Studer et al. (2010).

From the paper (2010), I quote the following :

> According to Batagelj (1988), the notion of a gravity center holds for any kind of distances and objects, even though it is not clearly defined for complex nonnumeric objects such as sequences. It is likely that the gravity center does not itself belong to the object space, exactly as the mean of integer values may be a real noninteger value. [...] Even though the gravity center may not be observable, equation (4) provides a comprehensive way to compute the most central sequence, the medoid, of a set using weights. Searching the x that minimizes equation (4) is equivalent to minimizing the sum of the weighted distances from x to all other sequences. (p.8).

They developed a R function in the library `TraMineR`. It actually enables to get p.values from co-variates using permutation tests.

The output looks like this :

```
Pseudo ANOVA table:
        SS df      MSE
Exp    1.7  1 1.700000
Res    9.6  8 1.200000
Total 11.3  9 1.255556
```

However, I fail to completely understand how to compute the Sum of Squares for such matrix (**manually if possible**), for both the `Total` and the `Explanatory` ? What is the "mean" or "center" in this context ?

Thank you.

**Data and codes**

```
library(dplyr) 
library(reshape2) 
library(TraMineR) 

# data from TraMineR # 

dt = structure(list(sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), Sep.93 = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("FE", "employment", 
"school", "training"), class = "factor"), Oct.93 = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("FE", "employment", 
"school", "training"), class = "factor"), Nov.93 = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("FE", "employment", 
"school", "training"), class = "factor"), Dec.93 = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("FE", "employment", 
"school", "training"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("sex", 
"Sep.93", "Oct.93", "Nov.93", "Dec.93"), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = "data.frame")

# To transform the data into COUNT data # 

dtm = melt(dt, id.vars = c('sex'))
dtmcount = count(dtm, sex, value)

# The `SS` is easily compute with # 

dtmcount %>% group_by() %>% 
  mutate(grandmean = mean(n)) %>% group_by(sex) %>% 
  mutate(SumSqtTotal = (n - grandmean)^2) %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% mutate(groupmean = mean(n)) %>% 
  mutate(SSW = (n - groupmean)^2) %>%
  group_by(sex) %>% mutate(SSB = ( grandmean - groupmean)^2) %>% group_by() %>%
  summarise(SST = sum(SumSqtTotal), SSW = sum(SSW), SSB = sum(SSB))

# Hamming distance function # 

 Ham = function(d){
  mat = matrix(0, nrow(d), nrow(d))

  len = nrow(d)
  mat = matrix(0, len, len)

  for(k in 1:len){
    for(i in 1:len){
      mat[k,i] = sum( ifelse( as.numeric( d[k, ] == d[i, ] ) == 1, 0 , 1) ) 
    }
  }
  return(mat)
}

used in the example, like this 
Ham(dt[,-1])

# The TraMineR Example # 

data(mvad)
library(dplyr) 

set.seed(10)
mv = mvad %>% group_by(male) %>% sample_n(5)

# compute the dissimilarity matrix 
mvad.ham <- seqdist(mvad.seq, method="HAM") 

# compute the discrepancy analysis 
d = dissassoc(mvad.ham, group = mv$male, R=10)
```

Ref :

Studer, Matthias, et al. "Discrepancy analysis of state sequences." Sociological Methods & Research 40.3 (2011): 471-510.

Gabadinho, Alexis, et al. "Analyzing and visualizing state sequences in R with TraMineR." Journal of Statistical Software 40.4 (2011): 1-37.

Comment: I understood it that you've got `n` cases by variables dataset, and cases are parted in several groups. So, you can compute SStotal, SSbetween, SSwithin quantities. Now, I'd claim that if you compute `n x n` distance matrix between the cases and that distances are squared euclidean then you also can obtain those three quantities. If that is what you are asking I could show you - tell me. Hamming distance for binary data is known to be identical to squared euclidean distance.

Comment: I can't, however, comment on your example of distance matrix. - It looks strange a bit (all values equal); and I'm likely not familiar with an algorithm `algorithm to compute pairwise dissimilarities` you mention.

Comment: Can you show me how to compute it ? In the Euclidien and Hamming cases. Thank you very much. Can you explain me in details what the `center` is ? and what the SST means here ?

Comment: Only euclidean case is theoretically correct. If Hamming or whatever distance appears to be actually a synomym (and I know that Hamming is) - then only euclidean case in needed.

Comment: I'm not R user and cannot explain you an R code. I can explain by words and formulas.

Comment: it's fine. Please do explain me the euclidean case. thanks. Apparently (Mielke and Berry 2007 cited in Studer 2010) argues that the SST can be generalised to other diss measures than the euclidean one.

Comment: I did not understand how you computed SS from your initial "contingency table". In order to compute SS statistics of ANOVA - what you requests explicitly, one needs quantitative features data!

Comment: @ttnphns thank you for your answer. What do you mean by quantitative features data ? I calculate in the traditional anova way.

Comment: Please show in your Q how you did it. 'Cause it is hard to understand from you data table - which columns there represent groups and which are the analyzed variable(s).

Comment: Is it ok now like this ?

Comment: Not at all. It is incomprehensible how SS are computed from your data snippet. It is not a good practice to give just code. Correct is to give code with all its intermediate results displayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46158/discussion-between-giacomov-and-ttnphns).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instruction how you can **compute sums of squares** **SSt**, **SSb**, **SSw** **out of matrix of distances** (euclidean) between cases (data points) without having at hand the `cases x variables` dataset. You don't need to *know* the centroids' coordinates (the group means) - they pass invisibly "on the background": euclidean geometry laws allow so.

Let $\bf D$ be the `N x N` matrix of *squared* euclidean distances between the cases, and $G$ is the `N x 1` column of group labels (`k` groups). Create binary dummy variables, aka `N x k` design matrix: $\mathbf G=design(G)$.

[I'll accompany the formulas with example data shared with [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/158239/3277) answer. The code is SPSS Matrix session syntax, almost a pseudocode-easy to understand.]

```
This is the raw data X (p=2 variables, columns),
with N=6 cases: n(1)=3, n(2)=2, n(3)=1
        V1            V2       Group
       2.06          7.73          1
        .67          5.27          1
       6.62          9.36          1
       3.16          5.23          2
       7.66          1.27          2
       5.59          9.83          3
------------------------------------

comp X= {2.06, 7.73;
          .67, 5.27;
         6.62, 9.36;
         3.16, 5.23;
         7.66, 1.27;
         5.59, 9.83}.
comp g= {1;1;1;2;2;3}.

!seuclid(X%D). /*This function to compute squared euclidean distances
                is taken from my web-page, it is techically more convenient 
                here than to call regular SPSS command to do it
print D.
    D
    .0000   7.9837  23.4505   7.4600  73.0916  16.8709
   7.9837    .0000  52.1306   6.2017  64.8601  45.0000
  23.4505  52.1306    .0000  29.0285  66.5297   1.2818
   7.4600   6.2017  29.0285    .0000  35.9316  27.0649
  73.0916  64.8601  66.5297  35.9316    .0000  77.5585
  16.8709  45.0000   1.2818  27.0649  77.5585    .0000

comp G= design(g).
print G.
    G 
  1  0  0 
  1  0  0 
  1  0  0 
  0  1  0 
  0  1  0 
  0  0  1 

comp Nt= nrow(G).
comp n= csum(G).
print Nt. /*This is total N
print n.  /*Group frequencies
  Nt 
  6 
  n 
  3  2  1
```

**Quick method**. Use if you want just the above three scalars. As mentioned in [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/158239/3277) or [here](http://the%20sum%20of%20squared%20deviations%20from%20centroid%20is%20equal%20to%20the%20sum%20of%20pairwise%20squared%20Euclidean%20distances%20divided%20by%20the%20number%20of%20points), *the sum of squared deviations from centroid is equal to the sum of pairwise squared Euclidean distances divided by the number of points*. Then follows:

Total sum-of-squares (of deviations from grand centroid): $SS_t= \frac{\sum \bf D}{2N}$, where $\sum$ is the sum in the entire matrix.

Pooled within-group sum-of-squares (of deviations from group centroids): $SS_w= \sum \frac{diag(\bf G'DG)}{2\bf n'}$, where $\bf n$ is the `k`-length row vector of within-group frequencies, i.e. column sums in $\bf G$. Without the summation $\sum$ you have the `k`-length column vector: $SS_w$ in each group.

Between-group sum-of-squares is, of course, $SS_b=SS_t-SS_w$.

```
comp SSt= msum(D)/(2*Nt).
print SSt.
   SSt 
   89.07401667

comp SSw= diag(t(G)*D*G)/(2*t(n)).
print SSw. /*By groups
   SSw 
   27.85493333 
   17.96580000 
     .00000000 
comp SSw= csum(SSw).
print SSw. /*And summed (pooled SSw)
   SSw 
   45.82073333

comp SSb= SSt-SSw.
print SSb.
   SSb 
   43.25328333
```

**Slower method**. Use if you will need also to know some multivariate properties of the data, such as eigenvalues of the principal directions spanned by the data cloud (needed, for example, in multidimensional scaling).

Convert $\bf D$ into its *double-centered* matrix $\bf S$, explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/12503/3277) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/183930/3277). As noted in the 2nd link, one of its properties is that $trace(\mathbf S)=trace(\mathbf {T})=SS_t$, and (first nonzero) eigenvalues of $\bf S$ are the same as of $\bf T$ - the [scatter matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22520/3277) of the original (or implied, hypothetical) `cases x variables` data.

```
comp rmean= (rsum(D)/ncol(D))*make(1,ncol(D),1).
comp S= (rmean+t(rmean)-D-msum(D)/ncol(D)**2)/2.
print S.
    S 
    6.63045    6.58188   -1.46444     .96961  -14.15579    1.43828 
    6.58188   14.51701  -11.86120    5.54205   -6.09675   -8.68299 
   -1.46444  -11.86120   13.89118   -6.18427   -7.24447   12.86320 
     .96961    5.54205   -6.18427    2.76878    2.49338   -5.58955 
  -14.15579   -6.09675   -7.24447    2.49338   38.14958  -13.14595 
    1.43828   -8.68299   12.86320   -5.58955  -13.14595   13.11701

comp SSt= trace(S).
print SSt.
   SSt 
   89.07401667
```

Of course, you can do likewise the double centration also on each group distance submatrix; the traces of the $\bf S$s will be each group's SSwithin, which summation yields pooled $SS_w$.

If you need [to compute](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/148883/3277) matrix $\bf C$ of *squared euclidean distances between group centroids*, compute these ingredients:

$\bf E= G'DG$;

$\mathbf Q= \frac{diag(\bf E)n^2}{2}$, (n is a row vector and diag is a column);

$\bf F=n'n$.

Then $\bf C= (E-\frac{Q+Q'}{F})/F$.

```
comp E= t(G)*D*G.
print E.
   E 
 167.1296 247.1716  63.1527 
 247.1716  71.8632 104.6234 
  63.1527 104.6234    .0000 

comp Q= (diag(E)*n&**2)/2.
print Q.
   Q 
 752.0832 334.2592  83.5648 
 323.3844 143.7264  35.9316 
    .0000    .0000    .0000 

comp F= sscp(n).
print F.
   F 
   9.0000   6.0000   3.0000 
   6.0000   4.0000   2.0000 
   3.0000   2.0000   1.0000 

comp C= (E-(Q+t(Q))/F)/F.
print C.
   C
    .0000  22.9274  11.7659 
  22.9274    .0000  43.3288 
  11.7659  43.3288    .0000
```

Of course, $SS_b$ - if you still don't know it - can be obviously [obtained from it](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/158239/3277) (within group frequency is the weight).

---

**Bonus** instructions. **How to compute** **SSt**, **SSb**, **SSw** **when you do have the original** `N cases x p variables` **data X**. Many ways are possible. One of the most efficient (fast) matrix way with data of typical size is as follows.

Matrix of group means (centroids), `k groups x p variables`: $\bf M= \frac{G'X}{n'[1]}$, where $[1]$ is the `p`-length row of ones; $\bf n$ is a row defined earlier; $\bf G$ also see above; $\bf X$ is the data with columns (variables) *centered* about their grand means.

Total scatter matrix $\bf T=X'X$, and $SS_t= trace(\mathbf T)$.

Between-group scatter matrix $\bf B=(GM)'(GM)$, and $SS_b= trace(\mathbf B)$.

Pooled within-group scatter matrix $\bf W=T-B$, and $SS_w= trace(\mathbf W)= SS_t-SS_b$.

```
X with columns centered
  -2.2333   1.2817 
  -3.6233  -1.1783 
   2.3267   2.9117 
  -1.1333  -1.2183 
   3.3667  -5.1783 
   1.2967   3.3817 

comp M= (t(G)*X)/(t(n)*make(1,ncol(X),1)).
print M.
   M 
  -1.1767   1.0050 
   1.1167  -3.1983 
   1.2967   3.3817 

comp Tot= sscp(X). /*T scatter matrix
print Tot.
print trace(Tot).
  Tot 
  37.8299  -3.4865 
  -3.4865  51.2441 
  TRACE(Tot) 
   89.07401667 

comp GM= G*M.
comp B= sscp(GM). /*B scatter matrix
print B.
print trace(B).
  B 
   8.3289  -6.3057 
  -6.3057  34.9244 
  TRACE(B) 
   43.25328333 

comp W= Tot-B. /*W scatter matrix
print W.
print trace(W).
  W 
  29.5011   2.8192 
   2.8192  16.3197 
  TRACE(W) 
   45.82073333
```

(If you do not center $\bf X$ initially, $\bf W=T-B$ persists, and gives the same $\bf W$ as before, however $\bf M$, $\bf T$, and $\bf B$ matrices will be different from what before.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just one point. The grand-centroid and the group-centroid are actually not "observed", and no computed. Unlike anova, where we compare values to mean(s), here we don't it. Right ? We are simply "summing" up the matrices ? I am not sure I fully understand the concept of "centroids" ?

Comment: Word "centroid" in multivariate statistic and in euclidean geomenry is of precise meaning "arithmetic mean" (multivariate, in multivariate situation). So, any plain arithmetic mean is a particular case of centroid. When you have cases by variables data, you can compute these centroids (means) explicitly as the coordinates - i.e. the values on the variables. When you don't have that data but have, say, euclidean distances instead, you can't compute the centroids as _coordinates_, still, you can compute _deviations_ of data points from the centroids as well as distances between the latter.

Comment: I looked at your example here (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/158210/k-means-why-minimizing-wcss-is-maximizing-distance-between-clusters/158239#158239) and I notice that the SSt computed from a k-means is not the same as the SSt on the raw distance matrix. Why is it so ?

Comment: @giacomoV, 1) What is "raw" distance matrix? 2) How do you define SSt - sums of squares or sums of squares of deviations (from centroid)? If you have comments to my _other_ answer please post a comment there, not here.

Comment: The sum of the entire matrix (as you explained in the *quick method*). Is the SSt different in the kmeans case ? I am looking for some references who goes in details in codes and examples but I can't really find any. Do you have any recommendation ? Don't you have a full example, step by step, with codes that I can reproduce by hand? I ran the euclidean distance on the data points you gave in your post just mentioned, but I don't get the same results as your `Matrix of squared Euclidean distances`. I also can't reproduce the `Its sum/2, the sum of the distances = 534.4441000` as you gave it.

Comment: Alright, I'll accompany my present answer with an example, every formula. In a couple of hours, wait.

Answer (score 2):

Sum of squares is closely tied to Euclidean distance. Hamming (on bits) is a special case, as it is the same as Euclidean (on bits), but **you cannot conclude from an arbitrary distance matrix what the SSQ etc. are**.

Recall how the sum-of-squares are usually defined, compared to Euclidean distance:
$$
SSQ(A,B) = \sum_{a\in A} \sum_{b\in B} \sum_i (a_i-b_i)^2
\\
= \sum_{a\in A} \sum_{b\in B} d^2_{\text{Euclidean}}(a, b)
$$

So *if* your distance matrix stores Euclidean distances (or squared Euclidean), then you can use that second line to compute SSQ.

If you have a different distance function, the result will usually be wrong (unless you use a different definition of "sum of squares" than the usual one; I believe you could use the second line, but this may cause trouble in other situations such as k-means).

Comment: Your second line $\sum_{a\in A} d^2_{\text{Euclidean}}(a, \mu)$ looks (tautologically with the 1st one) like a distance from point a to centroid mu (i-th? one). But the question of the OP is about _pairwise_ distances between data points.

Comment: Yes, I used the center as an example to not have another sum in there. But I will change it to a second set.